# C# LocationChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that I use to overlay things that I don't want the user to mess with at a given time. When I use this overlay form to cover an entire form, everything works beautifully. However, when I use it to cover a panel, the LocationChanged event never fires! I tried changing the panel's properties to see if something was preventing it somehow. I tried using Dock = Fill, I have also tried matching the size of its parent control and using anchors... All to no avail.

Is there something I am missing that would prevent the LocationChanged event from firing?

Overlay form:

```
Panel PanelToCover = new Panel();

public Overlay(Panel paneltocover)
{
    PanelToCover = paneltocover;


    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
    this.Location = paneltocover.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
    this.ClientSize = paneltocover.ClientSize;
    paneltocover.LocationChanged += PanelCover_LocationChanged;
    paneltocover.ClientSizeChanged += PanelCover_ClientSizeChanged;
    this.Show(paneltocover);
    paneltocover.Focus();
}

private void PanelCover_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = PanelToCover.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
}
private void PanelCover_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This works without an issue
    this.ClientSize = PanelToCover.ClientSize;
}
```

**Edit:**
I am silly. The panel's location will never change in respect to its owner. I was checking the PointToScreen value, watching it change, and wondering why the LocationChanged event never fired.

Comment: Why would the panel's Location change?  You generally only change the location of the Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The panel's `Location` property represents the location of the panel on its containing control (the form).  The panel is not moving with respect to the form, so `LocationChanged` never fires.

Comment: So doing this would work?
Form.LocationChanged += PanelCover_LocationChanged;

Comment: Yes It can work. But will advice you to change the method name to Form_LocationChanged to avoid ambiguity in future.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the panel is relative to the form, so if you're moving the form the location_changed event won't be triggered on the panel. That's why the event is not triggered.